# Ansible: unsupported parameters for lineinfile module

Tags: ansible

I really don't see the error in the following ansible task:

```
- name: Ensure home directories are created upon login
  lineinfile:
    path: /etc/pam.d/common-session
    search_string: 'pam_mkhomedir\.so'
    insertafter: 'pam_sss.so'
    line: 'session required pam_mkhomedir.so skel=/etc/skel/ umask=0022'
  tags:
    - ldap
    - pam
    - config
```

When executed I get the following error:

```
fatal: [ourcq]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Unsupported parameters for (lineinfile) module: search_string Supported parameters include: attributes, backrefs, backup, create, firstmatch, group, insertafter, insertbefore, line, mode, owner, path, regexp, selevel, serole, setype, seuser, state, unsafe_writes, validate"}
```

Answer (score 1):

What version of Ansible are you running? Most probably it's lower than 2.11.
(I had the same error on the most recent mint (21.3) that still has ansible 2.10.8)

The `search_string` option was added in Ansible 2.11, see [docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/lineinfile_module.html#parameter-search_string). You need to update to 2.11 or higher to be able to use that option.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that does what I want:
add the line `line` after the line containing `pam_sss.so` if the line does not already exists, meaning that the regex `pam_mkhomedir` is not already present.

```
- name: Ensure home directories are created upon login
  lineinfile:
    path: /etc/pam.d/common-session
    regexp: 'pam_mkhomedir'
    insertafter: 'pam_sss'
    line: 'session required pam_mkhomedir.so skel=/etc/skel/ umask=0022'
  tags:
    - ldap
    - pam
    - config
```

Answer (score -2):

It is worked for me in ubuntu 20.04:

```
$ sudo pip3 install ansible-core
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).